# Problems installing MicroPython Package mfrc522

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny, mfrc522

I purchased a 37 Raspberry Pi Pico sensor package from a company called Keyestone. In it is a RFID sensor that requires the mfrc522 package. Using Thonny I tried to install the mfrc522 package. When I try to download it, Using the "Tools/Manage Packages", Thonny initially tells me that the package doesn't look like a MicroPython package. I have successfully installed another package even though I initially got the same error. So, I went ahead and tried to install the mfrc522 package and get the error below. I'm working with a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I reinstalled Thonny but that didn't help.

Is there some other package that I should be using?

Thank you for your help.

Tom

```
Installing to temp directory
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\python.exe" -m thonny.plugins.micropython.minipip install --target C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph6nwm3cx mfrc522
Processing 'mfrc522'
Querying package metadata from https://micropython.org/pi/mfrc522/json
Could not find 'mfrc522' from https://micropython.org/pi
Querying package metadata from https://pypi.org/pypi/mfrc522/json
Inspecting version 0.0.7
'mfrc522' will be installed with pip (not having single tar.gz asset).
Installing with pip: ['mfrc522']
Collecting mfrc522
  Using cached mfrc522-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting spidev
  Using cached spidev-3.6.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting RPi.GPIO
  Using cached RPi.GPIO-0.7.1.tar.gz (29 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: spidev, RPi.GPIO
  Building wheel for spidev (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for spidev (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjow6fobs'
       cwd: C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wge7a33p\spidev
  Complete output (26 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'spidev' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
  creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcspidev_module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\spidev_module.obj
  spidev_module.c
  spidev_module.c(33): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'linux/spi/spidev.h': No such file or directory
  C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-c4ylp66q\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:755: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
          versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
  
          By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.
  
          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for spidev
  Building wheel for RPi.GPIO (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for RPi.GPIO (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wge7a33p\\RPi.GPIO\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wge7a33p\\RPi.GPIO\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-zoqbqqcq'
       cwd: C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wge7a33p\RPi.GPIO\
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\RPi
  copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\RPi
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\RPi\GPIO
  copying RPi\GPIO\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\RPi\GPIO
  running build_ext
  building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\source
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsource/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\source/py_gpio.obj
  py_gpio.c
  source/py_gpio.c(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
  source/py_gpio.c(200): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
  source/py_gpio.c(227): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  source/py_gpio.c(345): error C2373: 'output': redefinition; different type modifiers
  C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wge7a33p\RPi.GPIO\source\constants.h(29): note: see declaration of 'output'
  source/py_gpio.c(345): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
  source/py_gpio.c(359): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py clean for RPi.GPIO
Failed to build spidev RPi.GPIO
ERROR: Could not build wheels for spidev which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

minipip returned with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded mfrc522-python but it was a dummy file and didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The package [mfrc522 from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/mfrc522/) is only suitable for Python, not for MicroPython although it is installable of course.

I recommend having a look at the [Awsome MicroPython](https://awesome-micropython.com) page

> A curated list of awesome MicroPython libraries, frameworks, software and resources.

At their NFC section you can find [MicroPython NFC](https://github.com/rolandvs/micropython-nfc) which can be used to interact with MFRC522, or you give [micropython-mfrc522 by wendlers](https://github.com/wendlers/micropython-mfrc522) a try. According to the number of stars and forks on GitHub this might be the better lib